# Asp.Net Core 3.1 post request doesn't work with Angular 8 on server

Tags: asp.net, angular, post, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

It works on local or with Postman request. But when I've published files it's getting 'Unknown error'. I'm using Windows Authentication. I've tried it from Firefox then I'm getting this error below:
[firefox error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDpuF.png) . When I'd taken Firefox raw request and I'd pasted to Postman then It worked.

Here is my Controller method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ApiResult<OverTimePlanning> Post([FromBody]OverTimePlanning overTimePlanning)
    {
        logger.LogInformation("Planning Add started");
        var result = new OverTimePlanning();
        var apiResult = new ApiResult<OverTimePlanning>();
        ... Some codes are here ...
        logger.LogInformation("Planning Add ended");
        return apiResult;
    }
```

Here is my C# model class :

```
public class OverTimePlanning
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Guid GUID { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateStarted { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateEnded { get; set; }
    public int? ApproverUserId { get; set; }
    public string ApproverUser { get; set; }
    public string ApproverUserPhoto { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public OnayDurumu Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }
    public int UserCreatedId { get; set; }
    public string UserCreated { get; set; }
    public string UserPhoto { get; set; }
    public string ApproverComment { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Employee list
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<OrganisationUser> Employees { get; set; } 
}

public class OrganisationUser
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string Name  { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email  { get; set; }
    public string Photo    { get; set; }
    public string Manager { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
   
}
```

Here is my Angular service code:

```
saveOverTimePlanning(overtime: OverTimePlanning) {
const header = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
const options = { headers: header, withCredentials: true };
return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, JSON.stringify(overtime).replace(/_/g, ''), options);
}
```

Here is my Angular model:

```
import { OrganisationUser } from './organisationUser.model'
export class OverTimePlanning {
private _id: number
public get id(): number {
    return this._id
}
public set id(value: number) {
    this._id = value
}
private _guid: string
public get guid(): string {
    return this._guid
}
public set guid(value: string) {
    this._guid = value
}
private _unit: string
public get unit(): string {
    return this._unit
}
public set unit(value: string) {
    this._unit = value
}
private _dateStarted: Date
public get dateStarted(): Date {
    return this._dateStarted
}
public set dateStarted(value: Date) {
    this._dateStarted = value
}
private _dateEnded: Date
public get dateEnded(): Date {
    return this._dateEnded
}
public set dateEnded(value: Date) {
    this._dateEnded = value
}
private _approverUserId: number
public get approverUserId(): number {
    return this._approverUserId
}
public set approverUserId(value: number) {
    this._approverUserId = value
}
private _approverUser: string
public get approverUser(): string {
    return this._approverUser
}
public set approverUser(value: string) {
    this._approverUser = value
}
private _approverUserPhoto: string
public get approverUserPhoto(): string {
    return this._approverUserPhoto
}
public set approverUserPhoto(value: string) {
    this._approverUserPhoto = value
}
private _description: string
public get description(): string {
    return this._description
}
public set description(value: string) {
    this._description = value
}
private _shortDescription: string
public get shortDescription(): string {
    return this._shortDescription
}
public set shortDescription(value: string) {
    this._shortDescription = value
}
private _status: number
public get status(): number {
    return this._status
}
public set status(value: number) {
    this._status = value
}
private _dateCreated: Date
public get dateCreated(): Date {
    return this._dateCreated
}
public set dateCreated(value: Date) {
    this._dateCreated = value
}
private _dateUpdated: Date
public get dateUpdated(): Date {
    return this._dateUpdated
}
public set dateUpdated(value: Date) {
    this._dateUpdated = value
}
private _userCreatedId: number
public get userCreatedId(): number {
    return this._userCreatedId
}
public set userCreatedId(value: number) {
    this._userCreatedId = value
}
private _userCreated: string
public get userCreated(): string {
    return this._userCreated
}
public set userCreated(value: string) {
    this._userCreated = value
}
private _userPhoto: string
public get userPhoto(): string {
    return this._userPhoto
}
public set userPhoto(value: string) {
    this._userPhoto = value
}
private _approverComment: string
public get approverComment(): string {
    return this._approverComment
}
public set approverComment(value: string) {
    this._approverComment = value
}

private _employees: OrganisationUser[]
public get employees(): OrganisationUser[] {
    return this._employees
}
public set employees(value: OrganisationUser[]) {
    this._employees = value
}
```

}

```
export class OrganisationUser {
private _id: number;
public get id(): number {
    return this._id;
}
public set id(value: number) {
    this._id = value;
}
private _employeeID: number;
public get employeeID(): number {
    return this._employeeID;
}
public set employeeID(value: number) {
    this._employeeID = value;
}
private _name: string;
public get name(): string {
    return this._name;
}
public set name(value: string) {
    this._name = value;
}
private _shortName: string;
public get shortName(): string {
    return this._shortName;
}
public set shortName(value: string) {
    this._shortName = value;
}
private _userName: string;
public get userName(): string {
    return this._userName;
}
public set userName(value: string) {
    this._userName = value;
}
private _email: string;
public get email(): string {
    return this._email;
}
public set email(value: string) {
    this._email = value;
}
private _photo: string;
public get photo(): string {
    return this._photo;
}
public set photo(value: string) {
    this._photo = value;
}
private _manager: string;
public get manager(): string {
    return this._manager;
}
public set manager(value: string) {
    this._manager = value;
}
private _unit: string;
public get unit(): string {
    return this._unit;
}
public set unit(value: string) {
    this._unit = value;
}
private _level_: number;
public get level_(): number {
    return this._level_;
}
public set level_(value: number) {
    this._level_ = value;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned this:
You can't send raw/json request data with Windows credentials. Because newest browsers don't allow preflight (HttpOptions) requests with Windows Credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Statuscode zero usually is the cause of CORS error. Check the server side implementation of CORS.

Here is the offical docs of CORS middleware in .net : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1

In the startup just include the middleware:(from docs):

```
 readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                          builder =>
                          {
                              builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                                                  "http://www.contoso.com");
                          });
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{       
    app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but I've already added this CORS section. It's a different issue for me :) When dependency projects fired an error, global error handling middleware doesn't catch the exception. But the server has returned "CORS" error at this situation.